# Fedora server 32 install does not claim full disk

Tags: fedora

I have installed Fedora 32 Server on a, well, server and something weird has happened.
During instalation I claimed the full disk for Fedora, But it only created a 15GB partition for Fedora, see `lsblk` output.
Is this normal behaviour or did something go wrong during instalation?

```bsh
[gengar@localhost ~]$ lsblk
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0   472G  0 disk 
├─sda1              8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2              8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3              8:3    0 470.4G  0 part 
  ├─fedora-root00 253:0    0    15G  0 lvm  /
  └─fedora-swap00 253:1    0  15.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

I am extra confused because I can see that the old CentOS stuff is completly gone.

I tried to reinstall Fedora server. Just to see if that would fix this issue, but now something even more confusing has happened. The logic volume has the size I expect but the numbers does not match with what `df -h` reports.

```
[gengar@localhost ~]$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   472G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2            8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3            8:3    0 470.4G  0 part 
  ├─fedora-root 253:0    0 439.7G  0 lvm  /
  └─fedora-swap 253:1    0  15.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
[gengar@localhost ~]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     16G  1.6M   16G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   15G  1.9G   14G  13% /
tmpfs                     16G  4.0K   16G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda2               1014M  191M  824M  19% /boot
/dev/sda1                599M  8.6M  591M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                    3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000``
```

Comment: Your partition is /dev/sda3 which has a size of 470 GB, only the logical volume is currently limited to 15 GB which is smart. With LVM you can dynamically increase single logical volumes without touching the partition table. Also now you have the change to separate important directories (e.g. `/var` `/var/log` etc.) so your system will still be responsive even if one of the LVs is out of space.

Comment: Yes logic volumens sorry. But still weird (imo) that it only takes 15GB when I didn't asked for that limit and I know it is not enough space for this server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not normal, you should report a bug against Anaconda (Fedora installer) to [Red Hat bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/) (you should also attach logs from the installation to the bug report, installer logs are in `/var/log/anaconda`).

If you want to resize your `/` LV, first check free space in your volume group "fedora" using `vgs` command (column "VFree", it should be approximately 440g) and then resize the root LV `lvresize -L +<size> -r fedora/root00` (where size is the free space in your VG). You'll need to do this from a LiveCD (mounted filesystems can't be resized). And as with all storage changes, you might want to do a backup first.

Comment: Thanks it is a fresh install, so I will just try and reinstall and see if it happens again. If it does I will report a bug I have backuped the install logs.

Comment: I add the output after reinstall. This is really weird

Comment: It's even weirder now. It looks like the filesystem is smaller than the logical volume. That doesn't make sense. What does `xfs_info /` says about the size of the filesystem? (You should be able to grow it using `xfs_growfs /`, XFS supports online resize. But it is really weird.)

Comment: I found a "solution" so first of the second thing I experienced is apparently a known bug with the net installer. Secondly I tried `lvresize -L 100%FREE -r fedora/root00` after using DVD installer instead of the netinstall and that solved the problem. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: The default 15G root is the default for automatically partitioned Fedora Server systems (decided here: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/server@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/D7ZK7SILYDYAATRFS6BFWZQWS6KSRGDG/ and it's hard-coded into Anaconda)